# Reinstalled MacBook and Xcode, Validate App report missing private key

Tags: xcode, key, private

Because Xcode 10 simulator issue I had to reinstall my MacBook.
I didn't export my private key (Didn't think it was necessary, big lesson learned now).
I reinstalled Xcode 10, cloned the iOS App from Bitbucket. testing code. all good.
But I got "missing private key" error when I did "Validate App", which is one of my steps in submitting new App version to App Store.
This is the screenshot
[image]

This is what I have tried:
Goto Keychain, removed the key generated for my developer account.
Then back to Xcode, revoke certificate. 
But it only brings me back to where I was.

Can I somehow create a new key to replace this one I created on Sept 10, which has been lost during the machine restore? Thanks

Comment: I also tried to download the certification from developer account website and added it to my keychain. But it's still showing missing private key. There is a "revoke" button beside download button. Didn't try that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured it out after gone through several other threads. 
Basically just one thing needs to be done: Go to your apple developer account online, go to certificates and profiles, find your certificate in iOS production, REVOKE it. 
That’s all. Then during the validate process you will be prompted to generate a new certificate. Everything back to normal.